# date select widget with django model-based class view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

When using a class-based views associated with a model to render the form, how can I select the datetime picker widget to be displayed with DateTimeField? 
Or can I not use the model to render the form in this case and have to specify my own form class?

Answer (score 0):

It's about specifying the right widget for the the DateTimeField in your model. I don't think this has something to do with the fact that you are using a class vased view.

To add the widget to the model please see the docs: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields